# Normal Map is strangely scaled when rendered

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, normal-map

I have applied a diffuse image texture and normal map to this model. As you can see in material view the uv shows the texture as a clean uniform texture, however if i render it you can see that on the angle it is strangely scaled compared with the flat surface.

[image: what it looks like in the viewport]

[image: rendered with normal map]

I am confused because the normal map and color map both have the same uvs, why would the image unwrap uniformly but the normal map not.